# Should OpenID connect ID tokens be validated in the browser?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid

As I was working on a blog series about OpenID connect with Angular I was working with an Angular library for OpenID connect called angular-auth-oidc-client. This library is used for implementing OpenID connect implicit flow and does client validation of both the ID token and access token.

My questions are:

1. Since Angular apps lives in the browser, which contains javascript files that can be tampered with, by a mallicous user who has eg. sniffed another users access token, to disable ID token validation, **isn’t it pointless to do ID token validation in a browser**? I know the ID token is used by the client for verifying authentication, **but does it provide any security when this is done in the browser**?

   2. Would it be a better implementation **to not validate the ID token in the browser and instead use a front End server for validating ID token** before requesting a resource API?

My question is NOT about the specification of OpenID connect, but about using a browser for id token validation. I have created a blog post [here](https://blog.christianlydemann.com/post/openid-connect-part1-openid-connect-overview/), where im explaining OpenID connect on a practical level.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An ID Token is a security token.
Your client (Angular app) should verify any ID token sent by the OIDC provider to authenticate the user.
If this verification is not done, you expose your API to security issues by authenticating malicious users.
Please refer to [this specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) for details about the ID Tokens.

The access token is also a security token, but your client should not perform any verification and use it "as-is". **The string is usually opaque to the client**.
The verification of the access tokens is performed by the resource server (e.g. using the [Introspection Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) or checking self-contained access token).
Please refer to [this specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) for details about the Access Tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but please read my questions.
I know that the client uses the id token to verify the authentication of the requestions user. **My question was if it provides any security to do id token validation in a browser, where the js that does the validation can be changed by the user**. 
I have a blog post here about the working of OpenID connect [here](https://blog.christianlydemann.com/post/openid-connect-part1-openid-connect-overview/) and that explains the OpenID connect specification on a deeper level.

Comment: Well... My answer is clear: you have to verify the ID Token. No matter what party will use it (native app, JS script, front server...). You wrote `validating ID token before requesting a resource API`. You can check the ID Token first then send a request to the resource server (with access token). There is priority order here.I read your blog post and I can see some minor improvement to be done. The access token token is not necessarly a JWT (e.g. it can be complete random byte string). JWT can be encrypted (see RFC7516). Nice blog post anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The single page app's, SPA, **sole** purpose is to provide a human with a UX experience alternative to manually executing a jillion curl commands to backend micro-services.  Should the token validation fail, the SPA should provide a meaningful UX interaction to the human.

The SPA is participating an authentication exchange. It makes no sense for it to not take responsibility for validating the token. Attempting to delegate that responsibility to somewhere else is a **brittle practice** that needlessly widens the set of participants in the authentication exchange. In any distributed collaboration, the less participants the better.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned itself in the [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) that implicit flow is not a recommended option right now as other more secure options like PKCE is available.

About your question about ID token validation in the browser considering the sniffing of another user's access token doesn't come in the scope of the front end security as this is more about introducing transport layer security in the authentication mechanism. Please refer this [link](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/hi-tarun-d3860b5c52eb) for PKI best practices that can be implemented. Once we have a token sniffing done, the malicious user can go to what ever extend and impersonate as that original token holder and even if the token validation is happening in a front end server as you told, we cant invalidate the malicious user.

Answer (score -1):

Your API (API backend) should validate token for each request. Frontend just generates token and add it to each API request (see HTTP interceptors).

Comment: Please read my questions. I know the resource api should validate the access token and that was not my question. Front end doesn’t generate token, the authorization server does, but yes it sends it to the resource api as a bearer token :) 
But my question was if browser validation of id token provides any security since the user can minipulate with the js in the browser.

Comment: I agree with @lyzz it is about ID Token validation in the browser and not in the backend. For backend the token should be access_token.